# Is it possible to have powershell stop on ambiguous path when tab completing?

Tags: powershell

The current PS behaviour when tab completing is to complete with the first entry, and on successive tabs, scout through the other ones. If I have tens of entries that match the first characters I typed, I now either:

- tab forever until I find the one I need, or
- delete the long name, write more letters before I hit tab.

All of this is terribly inefficient. Is there a way to have it stop on ambiguous completion like in bash?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, natively, to do what you ask as far as I am aware of. Bash, has this, because the Bash team choose to add it for whatever their reasons and though PS has many Linux like alias, PS formatting is a different thing. I am not aware of any effort to make PS act like bash. PS is object based, Bash and the like is string based.

If you think this should be a thing, then submit a request to the PS GitHub uservoice site. Yet, it's not somehthign that I've ever seen on the uservoice or other like sites that communicate to the MS PS team.

You can change the some of how the listing appears, for example show vertical wide list, for example the emacs look. You do this by setting it up in your PS profile(s) by messing with the PSReadline options, and there are a lot of options using PSReadline, but that only works in the PS consolehost not in the ISE (and no place to make it so) or in the VSCode integrated console (the replacement for the ISE, it has been asked for here). Yet, since you can have multiple terminals open side by side in VSC, thus getting the consolehost natively, thus PSReadline, it's a low priority for the VSC integrated console from what I can tell.

> about_PSReadline
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-6

For example:

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1

# PSReadline Options
Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs
Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None 
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord tab -Function Complete
```

You can write your own wrapper to do something close to this or use Out-GridView as a GUI to show your listing and select from there.

For example:

> Out-GridView (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview
>
> Creating a Simplistic GUI Interface with Out-GridView
>
> https://mikefrobbins.com/2014/09/11/creating-a-simplistic-gui-interface-with-out-gridview
>
> Creating a GUI Using Out-GridView in PowerShell
>
> https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/02/17/creating-a-gui-using-out-gridview.aspx

Basically OGV< will show you your long list, you can select from there and have that show up in the command line or assign to a variable in a running script / function, etc.

Lastly, remember PS has been OSS for a while now, and if you think you have the skills to add this, then do a pull request and dev it up, and submit it back to see if it gets accepted.

***Update for the OP***

I did some more digging at this out of curiosity (and I don't mind the default behavior - well, that I an rarely need bash in my daily work.), putting this in your PS profile, should give you what you are after.

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete
```

Show, using the MS PSReadline doc, and this article...

[Emulating-Bash-GNU-Readline-with-PowerShell-30](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2012/09/12/Emulating-Bash-GNU-Readline-with-PowerShell-30)

… this should get you there.

Oh and just found this one, which is very similar to what you ask here, and points to the same info I've already given.

[How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash/37715242#37715242)